# Parallelizing a for loop to run simultaneously on multiple GPU cores?

Tags: matlab

I understand that you can use a `matlabpool` and `parfor` to run `for` loop iterations in parallel, however, I want to try and take advantage of using the high number of cores in my GPU to run a larger number of simultaneous iterations. I was wondering if there is any built in functionality to do this?

To my understanding, the method in which `MATLAB` runs code on the GPU is through a `GPUarray`, but that does not seem to parallelize a loop, only certain functions inside the loop.

For the loop that I am running, each iteration can run independently and the only variables that need to exist outside of the loop is the data to be processed (a 3-D array, where the first index is time, and each iteration is operating on a different time) and a 2-D output array where each iteration is storing the result for a particular time. Each time is independent.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With a `GPUArray`, you can run elementwise operations in parallel by structuring your algorithm in terms of MATLAB's `arrayfun`. Effectively, this implicitly loops over each element of your arrays, and can apply the body of a MATLAB function to each element. The doc is: [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/arrayfun.html).

There's a simple demo: [here](http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/distcomp/paralleldemo_gpu_arrayfun.html).

Comment: This is actually really helpful, however, there are a few parts of the function that I am working with that I cannot completely run everything element-wise (memory limitations). Thanks for the help!