# Using more than one GPU in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cuda, parallel-processing, gpu

this is the output of ginfo using Jacket/matlab:

```
Detected CUDA-capable GPUs:
CUDA driver 270.81, CUDA toolkit 4.0
GPU0 Tesla C1060, 4096 MB, Compute 1.3 (single,double) (in use)
GPU1 Tesla C1060, 4096 MB, Compute 1.3 (single,double)
GPU2 Quadro FX 1800, 742 MB, Compute 1.1 (single)
Display Device: GPU2 Quadro FX 1800
```

The problem is :

1. Can I use the two Teslas at same time (parfor)? How?
2. How to know number of cores are currently running/executing the program?
3. After running the following code and make Quadro (in use) I found it takes less time than Tesla despite Tesla having 240 cores and Quadro has only 64? Maybe because it's the display device?maybe becouse it's single precision and Tesla is Double precision?

```
clc; clear all;close all;
addpath ('C:/Program Files/AccelerEyes/Jacket/engine');
i = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
i_gpu=gdouble(i);
h=fspecial('motion',50,45);% Create predefined 2-D filter
h_gpu=gdouble(h);
tic;
for j=1:500
    x_gpu = imfilter( i_gpu,h_gpu );
  end
i2 = double(x_gpu); %memory transfer 
t=toc
 figure(2), imshow(i2);
```

Any help with the code will be appreciated. As you can see it's very trivial example used to demonstrate power of GPU, no more.

Comment: Reading through the Matlab documentation it seems that only one GPU is used for GPU accelerated calculations (some please correct me if I am wrong), and Matlab provides functions for selecting an GPU to use in the case of multiple GPUs installed on a single machine. 

Does this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473543/parallelizing-a-for-loop-to-run-simultaneously-on-multiple-gpu-cores help you at all?

Comment: As far as I can tell, Jacket is the only software that supports multi gpus for Matlab. You can find more information over here. http://wiki.accelereyes.com/wiki/index.php/Jacket_MGL

*Disclaimer* I work at Accelereyes and am involved with the development of Jacket.

Comment: I see you're using jacket from accelereyes. I hope this link about Jacket MGL will help: http://www.accelereyes.com/products/jacket_multi_gpu

Comment: can i get -- by profiling my code -- kernel/thread dimensions  jacket used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using two Teslas at the same time**: write a MEX file and call `cudaChooseDevice(0)`, launch one kernel, then call `cudaChooseDevice(1)` and execute another kernel. Kernel calls and memory copies (i.e., `cudaMemcpyAsync` and `cudaMemcpyPeerAsync`) are asynchronous. I've given an example about how to write a MEX file (i.e., a DLL) in [one of my other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322732/problem-with-nvmex-in-matlab/7325913#7325913). Just add a second kernel to that example. FYI, you don't need Jacket if you can do some C/C++ programming. On the other hand, if you don't want to spend your time learning the [Cuda SDK](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-cc-sdk-code-samples) or you don't have a C/C++ compiler then you're stuck with Jacket or [gp-you](http://gp-you.org/) or [GPUlib](http://www.txcorp.com/products/GPULib/) until Matlab changes the way that `parfor` works.

An alternative is to call [OpenCL from Matlab](https://code.google.com/p/opencl-toolbox/) (again through a MEX file). Then you could launch kernels on all the GPUs and CPUs. Again, this requires some C/C++ programming.

Answer (score 0):

From Matlab 2012, GPU array and GPU related functions are fully integrated into the MATLAB so you might not need to use Jacket to achieve what you are trying to do.

In sum, put `gpuDevice(deviceID);` before running GPU commands, then the following codes will be run on the `deviceID`th gpu. For instance

```
gpuDevice(1);
a = gpuArray(rand(3)); // a is on the first GPU memory
gpuDevice(2);
b = gpuArray(rand(4)); // b is on the second GPU memory
```

To run multiple GPUs. simply put

```
c = cell(1,num_device);
parfor i = 1:num_device
    gpuDevice(i);
    a = gpuArray(magic(3));
    b = gpuArray(rand(3));
    c{i} = gather(a*b);
end
```

You can see the GPU memory usage by typing `nvidia-smi` on the system command line.

This way of setting GPU id seems strange but it is the conventional way to set GPU id. In CUDA, if you want to use specific GPU then `cudaSetDevice(gpuId)` and the following codes will run on the `gpuId`th GPU. (0-base indexing)

----------------------EDIT----------------

Tested and confirmed on MATLAB 2012b, MATLAB 2013b.

Checked using `nvidia-smi` that the code is actually using different GPU memories. You might have to scale it very large `rand(5000)` and check very quickly since temporary variables `a` and `b` would disappear after the for loop ends

Comment: What version of MATLAB does this require, btw?

Comment: Tested and confirmed on MATLAB 2012b, MATLAB 2013b.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you're talking about the [PCT Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/) by MathWorks, while the original question was asking about the now [discontinued](http://blog.accelereyes.com/blog/2012/12/12/exciting-updates-from-accelereyes/) [Jacket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacket_%28software%29) package by AccelerEyes.

Comment: Ooops, I didn't read carefully, I should move the answer to a different thread

Comment: @ChristopherB.Choy: I think it's fine here, just wanted to clear any confusion

Comment: Okay, since the title is so similar, I'll leave it here. But I'll slightly modify so that it is relevant to Jacket.